# Performance issues with large MySQL tables with 100million of rows

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, database-partitioning

I've had some performance issues with MySQL tables and I'm trying to get some help. The SQL knowledge I have is pretty limited, so far over the years I was able to figure out most by using Google for solutions. At this point my the tables are so large that even doing something like a simple UPDATE query takes 1 second per row (usually its 0.0001s or something similar). My database is hosted on AWS using an Aurora MySQL engine and the instance is a db.t3.small. My largest table has 164million rows and keeps adding around 2million every day. I was reading about 2 possible solutions: Indexing and Partitioning. Right now I havent really indexed anything other than the main id which I dont use for anything:

Table metrics:

| Column | Type | Indexes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | `int(11)` | `PRIMARY, id_UNIQUE` |
| trackid | `varchar(100)` |  |
| plays | `int(15)` |  |
| source | `int(11)` |  |
| timestamp | `timestamp` |  |

Table tracks:

| Column | Type | Indexes |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | `int(11)` | `PRIMARY` |
| trackid | `varchar(100)` | `trackid` |
| trackname | `varchar(200)` |  |
| artistname | `varchar(200)` |  |
| artistid | `varchar(100)` |  |
| date_added | `timestamp` |  |

I suppose first of all since my joins happen on trackid and not id I should create an index on trackid for all my tables. Any other indexes I should create? Also, would partitioning help my case? I was thinking to split up all the tables into monthly snapshots and just union them on the fly, but I dont know if thats a good idea. I really dont know what the best practices are and if I can even do partitioning this late in the process since the data is so big. Thanks for the help

Comment: Indexes must be chosen for specific queries. You haven't shown any queries, so there's no way to suggest which indexes you need. You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really), or the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU).

Comment: Thanks Bill, its not that a specific query is slow. Anything really, like a basic query such as "UPDATE tracks SET trackname = 'some name' WHERE trackid = '1a2b3c4d'". Does that mean I should set an index on every field I change such as the trackname in this case?

Comment: You mostly only need indexes on the columns that you use in `WHERE`, `ON`, `GROUP BY`, or `ORDER BY`. That query should be fast since you have an index on `trackid`.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar this is already really helpful. Would partitioning help in my case too?

Comment: You might also consider a larger db instance type.

Comment: What about partitioning, would that help at all? Not sure if its worth going through all the effort

Comment: As @BenWhaley already said, you should consider getting a larger instance type. With that amount of data having a 2GB RAM is utterly low and especially using the burstable instance (you should check the CPU credit balance on the instance as well)

Comment: Partitioning has little impact on query performance, except in cases where you can explicitly restrict scans to a particular partition. See https://vertabelo.com/blog/everything-you-need-to-know-about-mysql-partitions/ for the benefits of partitioning.

Comment: Does "PRIMARY, id_UNIQUE" mean that you have both `PRIMARY KEY(id)` and `UNIQUE(id)`?  The letter is useless since the PK is already a `UNIQUE`.

Comment: If you will eventually be deleting "old" rows, then we can discus `PARTITIONing`.  Otherwise, I see no performance benefit (from what you have said so far.)